# Animating the constraints of a UIButton from the centre of the view to the right

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, swift

Ive got a button placed at the bottom of the view, and I'm trying to animate its programmatically added constraints to shift from the middle to the utmost right of the screen (basically till the button is not visible anymore). The duration needs to be up to 2 minutes and the user should be able to tap the button while it is animating.

- The animation shows, but the animation completes within half a second.

This is the code I have at the moment

```
func animateButton() {

    let leftMarginConstraint:NSLayoutConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: self.tapToSaveButton, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Left, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: self.view, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Left, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)

     let rightMarginConstraint:NSLayoutConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: self.tapToSaveButton, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Right, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: self.view, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Right, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)

    tapToSaveButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(CheckOutViewController.buttonPressed(_:)), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
    self.tapToSaveButton.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    self.view.addSubview(tapToSaveButton)
    self.view.addConstraints([leftMarginConstraint, rightMarginConstraint])

    self.view.layoutIfNeeded()

    self.constraintAnimation(120, delay: 1, animatedConstraint: leftMarginConstraint, andOtherConstraint: rightMarginConstraint, finalConstantValue: 500, options: [UIViewAnimationOptions.AllowUserInteraction, UIViewAnimationOptions.CurveEaseOut])
```

}

```
func constraintAnimation (duration:NSTimeInterval, delay:NSTimeInterval, animatedConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint, andOtherConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint, finalConstantValue: CGFloat, options:UIViewAnimationOptions) {
    UIButton.animateWithDuration(duration, animations: {
        animatedConstraint.constant = finalConstantValue
        andOtherConstraint.constant = finalConstantValue

    })

}

func buttonPressed(sender : UIButton)

{

    print("Tapped")
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
animatedConstraint.constant = finalConstantValue
        andOtherConstraint.constant = finalConstantValue
UIView.animateWithDuration(duration, animations: {
        self.view.layoutIfNeeded()

    })
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
view.layoutIfNeeded()
UIView.animateWithDuration(duration) { [unowned self] in
    constraint.constant = value
    self.view.setNeedsLayout()
}
```